# Why must I see my Ignored Tags on my homepage?

Tags: feature-request, tags, homepage

Not sure if this question has been asked/answered yet ... but, is there a way, or in the works, to hide the ignored tags on my homepage? I'm talking about the list that displays them. I have a lot of tags I ignore and it pushes any advertisements, recent tags, and recent badges out of sight. It would also be a nice option to hide my interested tags as well, as I know what I am interested in, and should I forget I can go look at my preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right - both those boxes should be moved to the profile page and not be displayed on the homepage as it just adds clutter. Maybe some nice jQuery magic can be used to provide a new way to interest/ignore tags from the homepage view.

Answer (score 1):

I like the current layout, because it allows me to check easely my ignored tags **and** add new ignored tags if I see a *new* tag that I want to add.

---

The power of greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Remove Ignored Tags
// @namespace      so
// @description    Remove Ignored Tags
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    function GM_init() {
        if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100);
        } else {
            jQuery_init(unsafeWindow.jQuery);
        }
    }

    GM_init();

    function jQuery_init($){
            $("#ignoredTags").hide();
    }
})();
```

Comment: There should be an option to show/hide it ... for those that don't care to see, that's all I am after.

Comment: @mattruma: or you could use Greasemonkey :)

Comment: @voyager ... I will give that whirl! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what must be done to this script to make it work in Chrome? It never gets bast the first if-statement, the jQuery part is always undefined apparently.

Comment: @Lasse: you could change all for a simple `(function(){document.getElementById("ignoredTags").style("display")="none";})();` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The list of ignored tags could be replaced with a small,simple, "3 ignored tags" link which would take you to your profile when clicked.